# Kafka wont listen to bootstrap server initially when added dlt config. It wait for localhost and then after sometime only listen to bootstrap server

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

i'm using spring-kafka 2.8.

What my app does - Listen to a topic in aws msk and publish those data to an api. If consumer throw any exception, it will send to a dead letter topic. So my app is a consumer.

My consumer factory is like below.

```
  Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
  config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, env.getProperty("kafka.consumer.bootstrap.servers"));
  config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, env.getProperty("kafka.consumer.group"));
  config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
  config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
  config.put("security.protocol", env.getProperty("kafka.security.protocol"));
  config.put("sasl.mechanism", env.getProperty("kafka.sasl.mechanism"));
  config.put("sasl.jaas.config", env.getProperty("kafka.sasl.jaas.config"));
  config.put("sasl.client.callback.handler.class", env.getProperty("kafka.sasl.client.callback.handler.class"));

  return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
}
```

```
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory =
            new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setCommitLogLevel(LogIfLevelEnabled.Level.DEBUG);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setMissingTopicsFatal(false);
    return factory;
  }
```

My consumer looks like this.

```
@RetryableTopic(
        attempts = "4",
        backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000, multiplier = 2.0),
        autoCreateTopics = "true",
        topicSuffixingStrategy = TopicSuffixingStrategy.SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE,
        include = {ResourceAccessException.class})
  @KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${kafka.consumer.topics}'.split(',')}", groupId = "#{'${kafka.consumer.group}'}")
public void consume(@Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic, @Payload(required = false) String message) {
   // my code
}

  @DltHandler
  public void dlt(String message, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
    log.info("Dead letter topic " + message + " from " + topic);
  }
```

But when i start the application, it initially try to connect to localhost even thought i have defined bootstrap servers.

[image]

[image]

This issue happened only after I added dead letter topic configs. (adding @retryabletopic annotation and @dltHandler method). Otherwise the app works fine.

Can someone please help me resolve my issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to solve above issue.

What i did was i changed the `autoCreateTopics` as false.

`autoCreateTopics = "true"`

And i found another issue where i havent added any producerconfig as producerFactory(). So i added below configs

```
@Bean
  public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, env.getProperty("kafka.consumer.bootstrap.servers"));
    config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    config.put("security.protocol", env.getProperty("kafka.security.protocol"));
    config.put("sasl.mechanism", env.getProperty("kafka.sasl.mechanism"));
    config.put("sasl.jaas.config", env.getProperty("kafka.sasl.jaas.config"));
    config.put("sasl.client.callback.handler.class", env.getProperty("kafka.sasl.client.callback.handler.class"));
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
  }

  @Bean
  public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
  }
```

Now its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using spring-boot; the retryable topics feature uses a `KafkaAdmin` to create the topics (see `AdminClient config` in your log).

You need to set `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=...` - you are only configuring the bootstrap for the consumers, Boot uses the property to configure the admin.

You should also use Boot's auto configured consumer factory instead of declaring your own bean.

Comment: I have read about spring boot's auto configuration for kafka. So according to my understanding, we dont need to create beans manually. What we have to do is simply set the correct props in our property file (like bootstrap server, group id....). am i correct?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: i found these props list as spring boot auto configuration and posted in here for anyone who interested.
  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.integration.spring.kafka.admin.client-id